# Selenium - Python webdriver path error system can't find the path specified

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, webdriver

Please help, whats wrong with the FF profile. I want to save a file from the website using Firefox and python webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import os
"""from bs4 import BeautifulSoup"""

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/html")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get("http://achecker.ca/checker/index.php")
assert "Web Accessibility Checker" in driver.title
options = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Options")
options.click()
check_WCAG10 = driver.find_element_by_id("radio_gid_4")
check_WCAG10.click()
elem = driver.find_element_by_id("checkuri")
input_url = "naturasiberica.ru"
elem.send_keys(input_url)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
# wait for result
try:
    element_exp_form = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "fileselect")))
except:
    driver.quit()
export_format = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("fileselect"))
export_format.select_by_value("html")
get_file = driver.find_element_by_id("validate_file_button")
get_file.click()
# wait for file_download
try:
    element_exp_form = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "fileselect"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
driver.quit()
```

Then I have an error:
[Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'c:\users\semashko\appdata\local\temp\tmpr7lojx/*.*'

Comment: did you find a solution ?

Comment: Perhaps this issue arises because Selenium is unable to locate the web driver path. To resolve this, you can download the appropriate web driver and place it in the designated location.

You can locate the compatible web driver for your installed version from the following sources:
- For Chrome: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
- For Firefox: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases